# businessobjects sdk java compatibility java version

Tags: java, sdk, java-8, business-objects, business-objects-sdk

Ok I am trying to make an SDK app and I am working with the newest Java version (I believe Java 8u60) and I have installed SAP BI 4.1 SP 6 on a VM.  When I ran my program first from the BOE scheduling functionality, I got this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/ghc/bo/extract/ExecuteExtract : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:735)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:716)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:336)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:59)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:250)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:243)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:372)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:344)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:313)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.plugin.desktop.program.internal.ProgramWrapper.main(ProgramWrapper.java:49)
```

and then I switched the compiler coompliance level to 1.7 and now Im getting this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/ghc/bo/extract/ExecuteExtract : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:735)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:716)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:336)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:59)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:250)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:243)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:372)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:344)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:313)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.plugin.desktop.program.internal.ProgramWrapper.main(ProgramWrapper.java:49)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I needed to set the compiler compliance level to 1.6.  OMFG

Comment: For your information, this limitation is due to the application servers we have to support.